# How to temporary lock scrolling on a long, single web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a long single webpage and highlight the individual sections of the webpage by a noticeable 'lock' feel whilst the user scrolls. When the section reaches the top and is occupying the full display it should disable scroll and then when the user scrolls again it should release and allow them to continue to the next section before it repeats the locking again.

I've looked around and not found what I'm looking for.

Any advice on solution or approach would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please post your findings and work done to solve the problem you have stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I would do `overflow: hidden;` for the body like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500 && $(window).scrollTop() < 750)
      $("body").addClass("ovh");
  });
  $("a").click(function () {
    $(".ovh").removeClass("ovh");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font: 10pt 'Segoe UI';}
.ovh {overflow: hidden;}
p.middle {margin-top: 750px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Body stops scrolling when the next text comes in.</p>
<p class="middle">Body stops scrolling here. <a href="#">Click</a> to release.</p>
<p class="middle">Some space</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of browsers is to scroll. To prevent this, you can use jQuery's `preventDefault`.

```
$(document).on("scroll touchmove mousewheel", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropogation();
    return false;
});

$(document.body).on("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 34 || event.which === 41) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```